# Need a way to store type of data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a battleship game for a practice exercise. I want the player to be able to type in two coordinates, and if those coordinates are a hit, it should return that. If those coordinates are the hit on a ship that sinks it, it should say so. I tried doing a dictionary that contains a list of lists, but I don't know how to search the values to see if the coordinates are inside it. I tried doing my_dict.values() to access the coordinates, but since the information is stored inside another list it won't find it. Here is some example code so this might make more sense.

```
my_dict = {"hats":[[2,3],[4,5]], "shoes":[[6,7], [8,9]]}

print my_dict.values()

if [2,3] in my_dict.values():
    print "Success!"
else:
    print "Failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the `values` and check if the position is in the current value.

For example:

```
my_dict = {"hats":[[2,3],[4,5]], "shoes":[[6,7], [8,9]]}

print my_dict.values()

for value in my_dict.values():
    if [2,3] in value:
        print "Success!"
    else:
        print "Failure"
```

You could also do this with `any`.

```
my_dict = {"hats":[[2,3],[4,5]], "shoes":[[6,7], [8,9]]}

print my_dict.values()    

if any([2, 3] in value for value in my_dict.values()):
        print "Success!"
    else:
        print "Failure"
```

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising. I'll check it out later, thanks!

Comment: I'm still a beginner in Python and I'm wondering if there is a preferable way to do this out of the two options you have shown?

Comment: @Supetorus The second one would be what I would go with, personally.